# What is the difference between control and adjust?

Tags: word-difference

What is the difference between control and adjust in the context of a sentence like "This can be used to adjust/control the degree of personalization"?

Answer (score 1):

Control has the definition: "determine the behavior or supervise the running of".  The definition of adjust is this:  "alter or move (something) slightly in order to achieve the desired fit, appearance, or result.  You do not always need to have the ability to adjust something in order to control it. Another option is to choose the word "manage".